# node_modules отсутсвует при запросе

Tags: asp.net, npm, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

https://www.screencast.com/t/1YCb5Hi9

здесь отсутсвует node_modules в пути, какой код показать?

https://www.screencast.com/t/p2FwLwuD

метод Configure в файле Startup.cs

```
        // подключаем файлы по умолчанию
        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        // подключаем статические файлы
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        // добавляем поддержку каталога node_modules
        app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions()
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "node_modules")
            ),
            RequestPath = "/node_modules",
            EnableDirectoryBrowsing = false
        });
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute("spa-fallback", new { controller = "home", action = "index" });
        });
```

установлены пакеты:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles

Answer (score 0):

нужно исправлять systemjs.config.js как правило где-то прописать map и/или packages, для jquery paths: { 'jquery': 'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'

но для ngx-uploader не получается.